# No CA2000 error when IDisposable created inside lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-2019, idisposable, roslyn-code-analysis

After refactoring the code below to remove the lambdas, I encounter a CA2000 error because `handler` is not being disposed (`MockDelegatingHandler` is `IDisposable`). Looking at the description for [CA2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2000?view=vs-2019), it would imply that `handler` is still in scope in the code below. It's not very clear what that scope would be in this case. What is it about being declared in a lambda that causes CA2000 not to apply to `handler`?

This code has no CA2000 error for `handler`

```
public void NoCA2000Example()
{
    var httpClientFactory = new MockHttpClientFactory((name) =>
    {
        var handler = new MockDelegatingHandler( // I would expect CA2000, but alas there is none
        async (request, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(expectedDTO));
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
                    System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                return await Task.FromResult(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
            });
        return new HttpClient(handler);
    });
}
```

This code has CA2000 error for `handler`

```
public HttpClient GetMockedClient(string name)
{
    var handler = new MockDelegatingHandler( // CA2000
        async (request, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(expectedDTO));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
                System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
            return await Task.FromResult(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
    return new HttpClient(handler);
}
public void CA2000Example()
{
    var httpClientFactory = new MockHttpClientFactory(GetMockedClient);
}
```

What is it about the first code block that it does not trigger a CA2000 error?

Comment: What happens if you put a `using` in to dispose `handler`? I'm assuming that `MockDelegatingHandler` is `IDisposable` from your description. When the `MockHttpClientFactory` invokes the outer lambda, `handler` will go out of scope before it's Disposed (and I'm guessing that why you are getting your error or warning

Comment: @Flydog57 I've made a few edits to provide more concrete examples. Yes, `MockDelegatingHandler` is `IDisposable`. Indeed, the CA2000 error is resolved if I dispose the handler, but in both cases, the `HttpClient` needs for the handler not to be disposed, so the dispose would need to be called elsewhere. My main concern is not how to resolve the error, but why the first example does not give CA2000.

Comment: This should be an easy thing to fix, and to explain. However, it would help if you put an actual stacktrace and exception message (at least the first few lines) as I am finding it hard to understand what is throwing when and what is the object that is being disposed.